# Spritekit Screen/Background Update

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Is it possible to get 2 positions from the same `SKSpriteNode` in the `-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` method?

I am making a demo. A ball is shot from a random point outside of the screen. I want to get the ball's direction and an array of positions so that I can do something based on it. But when I use the `update:` method, it seems that it fills the array in each update. How do I add only one `SKSpriteNode` to the array for each update?

```
NSMutableArray *nodePos;
int returnPosCount;

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if ([self childNodeWithName:@"//ball"]!=nil){
    returnPosCount++;
    if (returnPosCount == 15) {
        SKNode *node = [self childNodeWithName:@"//ball"];
        [nodePos addObject:node];

        if ([nodePos count]>4) {
             [nodePos removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"%@",nodePos);


        }
        returnPosCount =0;
    }

NSLOG:    
<SKSpriteNode> name:'ball' (64 x 64)] position:{-127.63968658447266, 135.19813537597656} 
<SKSpriteNode> name:'ball' (64 x 64)] position:{-127.63968658447266, 135.19813537597656} 
<SKSpriteNode> name:'ball' (64 x 64)] position:{-127.63968658447266, 135.19813537597656}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not filling the array in each each update. You are seeing the array full, because you are only printing the data when it is full. Just move your `NSLog` outside the `[nodePos count]` condition.

Now the reason why you have the same value is because you are adding the node, instead of its position at each update. Since the node is a reference, you will have an array full of references to the same object, thus obtaining the same position. You should build an array of `CGPoint` instead of an array of `SKNode`.

To do so, try changing:

```m
[nodePos addObject:node];
```

To

```
[nodePos addObject:node.position];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding the CGPoint into the array worked. I hit thumb up but I don't have enough reputation to show it. Thanks a lot.